# tensorflow output layer configuration for classification task

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to teach my first AI with `google colab` and `tensorflow`.

**`.predict` method work is not clear to me.**

---

I have following `dataset` example:

| classification | Input 1 | Input 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.22 |
| 1 | 0.333 | 0.4 |
| 4 | 0.55 | 0.6 |

Expected classes are `1` or `4`. Dataset contains 50% of each.

**My code is:**

1. Slice Data:

```
  features = df.iloc[1:, 1:]
  labels =  df.iloc[1:, 0]
```

2. Build Model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='tanh', input_shape=(82,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(256,), activation='tanh'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

3. Train Model:

```
model.fit(x=features, y=labels, shuffle=True, epochs=1)
```

**Results**

result of **`.predict`** method is always `[[1.]]`.

But I think that is should be smth like:
`[1: 0.4][2: 0.88]`

where: `1 and 4` are `classifications` and `0.4 and 0.88` are `probability`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in the configuration:

1. `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')`, change this to `tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')`
2. Since your labels are in integer format, you need to change your loss function to `model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`

Also, the way your dataset is formatted and by means of softmax, you will never have an output like you described :

> But I think that is should be smth like: [1: 0.4][2: 0.88]

The sum of probabilities will always sum up to `1` in your context.

Comment: I have `4` classes as possible output. But by mistake I started classification numiration from 1 (not from 0). So total number of output layer neurons that `keras` expects is `5`. And as a result I get an array of 5 values. Index `1-4` are my classes. I am wondering if element `0` has some math meaning? like "ok, input data is too noisy so I don't know what class the data belongs to"

Comment: Or it is just corruption of predictions and does not have any meaning?

Comment: So if you have exactly N label values, your softmax should be equal exactly to N.  The catch in your observation is that sparse_categorical_crossentropy expects your label_indices to start from 0 indeed... so if you have 5 labels, you would have labels [0,1,2,3,4] instead of [1,2,3,4,5].